# Model does not have values for ListBoxFor in MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am able to display values in ListBoxFor control from controller to view. However when I move values from one listbox to another and post the view the model on controller side does not preserve the values in the listboxes.

### Here is my Model

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
  public class EmployeeClass
  {
    public int EmpCode { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
  }

   public class EmployeeViewModel
  {
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public list<EmployeeClass> AvailalableEmployee { get; set; }
    public list<EmployeeClass> SelectedEmployee { get; set; }

    public int [] AvailableEmpCodeArray { get; set; }
    public int [] SelectedEmpCodeArray { get; set; }
  }
}
```

### Here is my Controller

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult EmployeeDisplayTool()
        {   
            EmployeeViewModel model = new EmployeeViewModel();

            model.Department = "Techology"
            model.AvailalableEmployee.Add(new Employee(1,"Emp1"));
            model.AvailalableEmployee.Add(new Scenario(2,"Emp2"));
            model.AvailalableEmployee.Add(new Scenario(3,"Emp3"));

            model.SelectedEmployee.Add(new Scenario(4,"Emp4"));
            model.SelectedEmployee.Add(new Scenario(5,"Emp5"));
            model.SelectedEmployee.Add(new Scenario(6,"Emp6"));
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmployeeDisplayTool(EmployeeViewModel model)
        {
            //model.Department is populated as "Technology"

            //All of the follownig collections are null.
            //model.AvailalableEmployee is null.
            //model.AvailableEmpCodeArray is null.

            //model.SelectedEmployee is null.
            //model.SelectedEmpCodeArray is null.
        }
    }
}
```

### Here is my View and JavaScript

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table id="MainTable" border="0">  
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Department, new { id = "txtDepartment" })
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>     
    <td>
       @Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.AvailableEmpCodeArray, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailalableEmployee, "EmpCode", "EmpName", Model.AvailableEmpCodeArray), new { id = "lbxAvailableEmployees" })
    </td>         
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="btnSelectEmployee" value=" >> "/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="btnUnSelectEmployee" value=" << "/>
    </td>
    <td>
         @Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.SelectedEmpCodeArray, new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedEmployee, "EmpCode", "EmpName", Model.SelectedEmpCodeArray), new { id = "lbxSelectedEmployees" })
    </td>         
</tr> 
</table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {  
        $('#btnSelectEmployee').click(function(e) 
        { 
            var SelectedEmps = $('#lbxAvailableEmployees option:selected');  
            if (SelectedEmps.length == 0) 
            {  
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('#lbxSelectedEmployees').append($(SelectedEmps).clone());  
            $(SelectedEmps).remove();  
            e.preventDefault();  
        });  

        $('#btnUnSelectEmployee').click(function(e) 
        {  
            var SelectedEmps = $('#lbxSelectedEmployees option:selected');  
            if (SelectedEmps.length == 0) 
            {  
                e.preventDefault();  
            }  
            $('#lbxAvailableEmployees').append($(SelectedEmps).clone());  
            $(SelectedEmps).remove();  
            e.preventDefault();
        });  

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `HttpPost` action you cannot expect the `AvailalableEmployee` and `SelectedEmployee` collections to be populated. That's due to the nature of how HTML works. Only the selected values are sent to the server when you submit the form. The text values of the select fields are **never** sent to your server when you submit the form.

So all you can hope of getting populated inside this HttpPost action is the `AvailableEmpCodeArray` and the `SelectedEmpCodeArray` collections. They will contain the values of the **selected** items in the corresponding select fields. Notice that I have bolded **selected**. This means that only if you select any items in the corresponding boxes those collections will be bound. If you don't select anything, they will remain null and that's perfectly normal.

Here's an example of the user that has selected nothing. He just used the `<<` and `>>` buttons to toggle the values between the lists, but please notice how absolutely nothing is selected:

[image]

Notice how **nothing** is selected? So that's all you will get in your controller action - **nothing**.

Now please compare with the following screenshot:

[image]

Do you see the difference? Notice how the user explicitly selected the `Emp2`, `Emp5` and `Emp6` values (using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select multiple values)? That's what you're gonna get inside your HttpPost action. The `AvailableEmpCodeArray` collection will contain a single element with the value of `2` and the `SelectedEmpCodeArray` will contain 2 elements with the values of `5` and `6`.

Now to your second problem. If you intend to redisplay the same view from your HttpPost controller action the first thing you need to ensure is that you have assigned values to the `AvailalableEmployee` and `SelectedEmployee` collections. This should be done the same way you did in the HttpGet action:

```
model.AvailalableEmployee.Add(new Employee(1,"Emp1"));
model.AvailalableEmployee.Add(new Scenario(2,"Emp2"));
model.AvailalableEmployee.Add(new Scenario(3,"Emp3"));

model.SelectedEmployee.Add(new Scenario(4,"Emp4"));
model.SelectedEmployee.Add(new Scenario(5,"Emp5"));
model.SelectedEmployee.Add(new Scenario(6,"Emp6"));
```

or if those values are coming from a database you will have to re-query this database inside the HttpPost action because those values, as I already explained, will never get bound from the view.

Comment: Thanks Darine for the quick response. How can I get the values stored in both the listboxes? User will select the values from one listbox to another and then perform other operations before clicking on the submit button.

Comment: The user must **select** the values if you want those values to be sent to your server. That's how HTML works and please learn the basics of HTML. If the user doesn't select anything no matter that you have toggled them between the select boxes, nothing's gonna be sent to the server. I will update my answer with screenshots for you to understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes I am new to HTML and learning basics of HTML...Is there any other way I can get values in controller?

Comment: I have updated my answer with screenshots. Hopefully you will now understand. You must select the values that you want to be sent to the server. That's how HTML works. Also if you are new to HTML I very strongly suggest you heading towards the [`w3.org`](http://www.w3.org/) site and start learning it before even getting into ASP.NET MVC. If you don't know the basics of HTML, you really don't need to waste your time with ASP.NET MVC because you will find lots of things strange and you will have hard time understanding them.

Comment: Thanks Darin....In my case values are selected when they are moved but then user can perform other operation such as modify department name, unselect some other values. When user clicks on submit then the changes should get saved to the database. In order to do that I need to know original list of values in both the listboxes and the changed list....So looks like I will have to find someother way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you will have to find another way. What I can tell you is that if the values are not selected at the very moment you submit your form to the server, as shown in my screenshots, you will get nothing in your controller action due the very basic nature of HTML. So I guess a javascript nightmare awaits you in *remembering the values that the user selected and automatically reselecting them before submitting the form*.